# replacing jquery google cdn with a new version dynamically

Tags: plugin-development, jquery, hooks

I do not have much experience with WordPress and i have one issue that i will have to fix.
My Theme loading an older version of jquery (1.8.3) via google cdn and because of this library my few plugins not working properly. I have test my website with default WordPress theme, and plugins started to work. I have tried to find this library so that i can replace with a newer version but i was not successful. This is a custom theme and i do not know the developer of this theme.
So is there any way that i can replace this dynamically with WordPress hooks.
Apologize if i am wrong but i do not have any alternate solution in my mind right now.
Your help will be much appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: there is a way but it is unlike to actually solve your issues. You need to invest the time and fix all the technical debt the site incurred, or in other words make sure everything works with current version and fix all the problems which will arise from such a transition

Comment: Typically when a developer does this, it's because they have not made the site compatible with newer versions of jQuery. To truly fix it as Mark has noted you'll probably need to make a lot of other adjustments. It may be worth finding a newer theme that is close to what you're looking for and developing a custom child theme, rather than trying to retrofit your old theme.

Comment: `I have tried to find this library so that i can replace with a newer version but i was not successful.` do you have access to the files?

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. I can see this link as a google cdn. But i could not find this in theme files. There are few errors in console like jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: type property can't be changed